# 'data' callback with two arguments does not print buffer.toString() as string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using process.openStdin() object in node to get input, the output is a buffer if the callback function has two arguments:

```
var stdin = process.openStdin();

stdin.on('data',function(err,chunk){
    if(err)
    {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(""+chunk.toString('ascii'));
});
```

Input: `abcd`

Output: `<Buffer 61 62 63 64 0a>`

But if the callback function is instead given a single argument like so:

```
var stdin = process.openStdin();

stdin.on('data',function(chunk){

    // if(err)
    // {
    //  console.error(err);
    //  return;
    // }
    console.log(""+chunk.toString('ascii'));
});
```

Then the output matches with the input (i.e., output is `abcd`). Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`data` events](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) do not have an `err` parameter, they only have the one Buffer/string parameter.

If you want to listen for errors, you will need to separately listen for the [`error` event](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_event_error) on the stream.